# Prove: For any real number $a$, $b$ : $|a - b| \ge |a| -|b|$

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value, real-numbers

I think this question has to do with field axioms so was wondering if you can claim that 
$$|a - b| - |a| - |b| \ge 0$$ and go from there.

Comment: Try using the triangle inequality.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 5):

By the triangle inequality we have

$$|a|=|(a-b)+b|\le |a-b|+|b|$$
so
$$|a|-|b|\le |a-b|$$

Answer (score 1):

One can use the triangle inequality of course, but I think it is more instructive to instead use the fact that, given fixed magnitudes for $a,b$, the quantity $|a - b|$ is maximized when $a,b$ have opposite signs and minimized when they have the same sign. You can then work through all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the triangle inequality if I'm not wrong:

$|a-b| = |a + (-b)| \geq |a| + |-b| \geq |a| - |b|$

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: As @SamiBenRomdhane has said it is incorrect!

Comment: Yes, of course.
$|a-b| = |a+(-b)| \leq |a| + |-b| \leq |a| - |b|$

EDIT: I dont know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ |a| = |(a-b)+b| \le |a-b| + |b| $, and therefore one have that $|a|-|b|\le|a-b|$.

Comment: perfect,thank you, i really need learn how to write with  symbols.

Comment: It is enough just following the edits! :)